# PHP imap_fetchbody - how to combine FT_UID and FT_PEEK?

Tags: php, imap

I want to return the body of and IMAP message by using the unique number - called by:

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'SINCE ' . date("Y-m-d"), SE_UID);
```

and returning the body by :

```
$mime = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "", FT_UID);
```

However, I don't want the imap_fetchbody command to set the message to SEEN, and I would like to use FT_PEEK for it.

However the imap_fetchbody doesn't allow for an array to be used as the fourth argument.

So how do I combine the two options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit mask: or them together.

```
$mime = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "", FT_UID|FT_PEEK);
```